# time complexity condition among merge-sort and bubble-sort?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, asymptotics, contest-math, computer-science

I ran into a strange note as follows:

we consider `bubble sort` time complexity as: $c_1n^2$ and `merge sort` time complexity as: $c_2n\log_2n$  $(1\leq c_1 \leq c_2)$ then:

for any $n$ such that $(n>2)$ `merge sort` is faster than `bubble sort` when we have:  $\frac{n}{2}> (\frac{c_2}{c_1})^2$.

Anyone could point me how these formula created !!? any idea about how this formula was derived?

Answer (score 2):

If $x>0$ then $\log_2(x) \le \sqrt{2x}$. So, if $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is such that $n \ge 2$ and $\frac{n}{2} > \big(\frac{c_2}{c_1}\big)^2$, then $c_2 < c_1\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}}$, yielding
\begin{equation}
   c_2 n \log_2(n) < c_1\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} n \log_2(n) \le c_1\sqrt{\frac{n}{2}} n \sqrt{2n} =  c_1 n^2 .
\end{equation}